# Browser / silverlight configuration

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight

We've got a locked down Panasonic Toughbook running a WPF program with an IE browser control.  This control hosts a webpage that enables webcam access for the application.  The first time the app is run on a new system, we get a silverlight popup that says "Do you want to allow camera and microphone access?"

Is there any way to preconfigure the system so access is always enabled and the user doesn't see this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is controlled by a registry entry:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppDataLow\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\Permissions\<>]
"WebcamAndMicrophone"=dword:00000011